# Adding date stamp to entered comments

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column, where I type a comment. This can change every day. I wonder if there is a possibility to have Excel automatically add the date (in the format DD/MM) in front of the comment (perhaps via a userform)?

The comment should be added to any comment that's already in the field, so it doesn't overwrite, but accumulates.

Also, today, the comments are added via a data validation list (with no hard stop). I'd like to continue with that, if at all possible.

Comment: Is there any vba code you already have? please show it in your question...

Answer (score 0):

I would create the following and assign a shortcut key (Developer tab->Macro->select AddTimedComment->click Options)

```
Public Sub AddTimedComment()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim comment As String

    Set c = ActiveCell.Cells(1)
    comment = Format(Now, "dd/MM") + ": " + InputBox("Enter a Comment", "Comment")
    c.AddComment comment
End Sub
```

An InputBox prompts for the comment's text. The code then appends the current date to the beginning of the text.

Comment: I can get as far as the Developer tab and locate the Macros icon, but from there I don't know what to do. Can you help, please?